# Is it true that $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $(1+x^2)f''\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ imply $xf'\in L^1(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Assume $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $(1+x^2)f''\in L^1(\mathbb R)$. Can we say that $xf'\in L^1(\mathbb R)$?

It looks like a weighted Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation result, but it is not so easy to find information on this estimate online. I would like to see a proof, a reference that discusses this or related estimates, or a counterexample.

---

***Remarks***: we know that $f'$ is bounded, continuous and goes to zero at infinity. Moreover, $f'\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ by the usual Gagliardo-Nirenberg estimates.

One can try to estimate the absolute value of $f'(x)$ using
$$ |f'(x)|\leq\int_x^{+\infty}|f''(s)|ds\leq\int_x^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+s^2}[(1+s^2)|f''(s)|]ds\leq \frac{C}{1+x^2}$$
(the last inequality follows only for $x\geq 0$, but the bound holds for all $x$ by symmetry). Thus, $xf'$ is "almost in $L^1(\mathbb R)$". So, the question sounds at least meaningful.

Comment: Stop short of your last estimate (i.e., leave the last integral as is, **before** the $\frac{C}{1+x^2}$), multiply by $x \geq 0$ and integrate $\int_0^\infty ... dx$. Apply Fubini's theorem. Can you complete the proof?

Comment: You are right, it was so easy. Thank you!